# How to specify the oracle database url for Carbon data source creation?

Tags: datasource, oracle12c, wso2, wso2-esb

The issue is that I am unable to connect to oracle database from the Carbon console while creating a datasource to a schema. The error is:

```
ERROR - DataServiceAdmin Could not connect to database jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/ORADB12c with username WSO2_TUT
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
```

I have a local installation of an Oracle database (12c). I would like to create a datasource on Carbon for a schema I have created on this database.

While providing the connection parameters I have selected to test the connection and the above error occurs.

I have added ojdbc6, then deleted and added ojdbc7 instead, then deleted and replaced with ojdbc14 to the directory of the WSO2 Enterprise Integrator:

```
D:\WSO2\EnterpriseIntegrator\6.5.0\lib
```

After that I restarted the server. When trying to re-create the datasource with the same credentials, I get this authentication error for some reason.

The connection details:

```
Datasource Id*      oracle_DS
Datasource Type*    RDBMS     
Database Engine*    Oracle
Driver Class*       oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
URL*                jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/ORADB12c
User Name       WSO2_TUT
Password        ********
```

I don't know what's missing here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but here's the configuration that I use to connect to a oracle 11 database.

```
Datasource Type:    RDBMS
Datas Sourec Provider:   default
Driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
URL:    jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:TNS_Listener
User name: myUser
Password: myPassword
```